# Font weight in windows store app

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm tryign to set my font weight propert to bold. But can't do that. So How can i set my font weight property to bold in c# code?

tbgc1.FontWeight.Weight = ?;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using Windows.UI.Text;

....

tbgc1.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
```

See FontWeight class on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.fontweights%28v=win.10%29.aspx)